# Is /g also greedy in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

```
g -- This option finds all occurrences of the pattern in the string
```

Does that mean that it is greedy? Because it makes the regex engine parse the entire string and not return at the first match. That is what non greedy matching is meant right. Can it be even classified as greedy or non greedy?

Comment: `g` is a __modifier__.  Your regex would define whether it's greedy or not.

Comment: Your understanding of _greedy_ is wrong.

Comment: Read the _fantastic_ documentation.  `perldoc perlre` might help.

Comment: Read this section of regular-expressions.info to learn about greediness: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: No, `/g` has nothing to do with greediness (the "g" in this case stands for "global".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greedy will consume as much as possible.

So for example `<.+>` will match whole `<EM>first</EM>`

However `<.+?>` will match only `<EM>` as it is lazy matching.

Now you must understand that `/g` modifier can be used with both greedy matching and lazy matching.

For example,

```
<EM>first</EM>
```

and you use `<.+>/g` it will replace full expression with specified one.

However `<.+?>/g` will replace  `<EM>` and `</EM>` only with specified expression.

Answer (score 2):

g is the global flag. It means that it will keep looking for matches after it finds one.

g is **not** greedy. The term greedy in regex is used to indicate that a token will match as many characters as possible, giving back as needed. Eg. `\w+`

A possessive match indicates that a token will match as many characters as possible, without giving back. Eg. `\w++`

Comment: Re "g is not greedy", Only in the sense that apples aren't greedy. Greediness or the lack thereof is not a quality that can be applies to the g flag, its effect or apples.

Comment: I meant it's not greedy as in, it's not called the "greedy flag". It's the global flag.